# Team A has 60% probability of winning a 3-game series, what is the probability of Team A winning a single match.

Tags: probability, gambling

This is driving me insane because it does not seem too difficult of a problem and solving it would ease my life a little.

Some background: I make estimates in esports and try to find edge over the betting markets. Most of the games are 3-game series so visualising team power ratings is easiest that way. I end up having a BO3 probability and then run into the problem of changing it to BO1 probability. As of now I figure it out by "testing" it in my excel spreadsheet, since I know how to make a BO1 probability into BO3.

In this case we also assume that all games in the BO3 series are identical probabilities.

Right now I know that:

$X=Y²+(2*((1-Y)*Y²))$

and

$1-X=(1-Y)*(1-Y)+(2(Y*(1-Y)*(1-Y)))$

Where X is BO3 probability and Y is BO1 probability. I don't think Y is solvable here though.

Just to be clear: BO3 means best of 3 game series and BO1 means a single match.

Thanks a lot in advance to anyone that bothers to help me on this one.

Comment: Any [cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) is solvable.

Comment: Are you assuming that team $A$ has a constant probability of beating team $B$ in a single match over the series?  For a math problem, that would be a sensible assumption, but not for any real world modeling.

Comment: Yes I am assuming that. Also I don't think it's that bad of an assumption in real world either, since I'm using the result to compare different bets. For example if BO3 winner odds are 1.80 and match 1 winner odds are 1.95 which one is the better bet if I think BO3 probability is 59%. Spoiler, the better bet is the match 1 winner bet with 56% probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume winning a 3 game series refers to winning 2 out of 3 and they will continue playing even if they win the first 2. Let $X$ be the event that team A wins and Y be the event they lose, there are 4 scenarios where they win $XXX, XXY, XYX, YXX$. Now let $P(X) = x, P(Y) = 1-x$ be the probability they win a game and lose a game respectively.

We know that $x^3 + 3x^2(1-x) = 0.6$ which gives us the solution $x \approx 0.57$

I think this should be correct!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The result seems to be correct. Maybe I'm dumb, but I'm still having hard time typing the formula in my excel. Could you show the formula that solves x

Comment: The formula is $x^3 + 3x^2(1-x) = 0.6$, just solve for $x$!